# why are two paragraphs being added on wordpress custom excerpt function used?

Tags: php, wordpress

I'm trying to develop wordpress site, where I'm using a custom excerpt function at front-end to display my post content. code is the following:

```
<h5 class="post-title"><a href=" <?php the_permalink() ?> "> <?php the_title() ?> </a></h5>
<?php the_post_thumbnail('home') ?>
<p class="content excerpt"> <a href="<?php the_permalink() ?>"> <?php news_excerpt(25) ?> </a></p><hr />
```

But, the problem is that two content showing paragraphs are adding at browser output. The output is the following:

```
<p class="content excerpt"> <a href="http://localhost/wordpress/index.php/2021/01/11/%e0%a6%9f%e0%a6%bf%e0%a6%95%e0%a6%be-%e0%a6%aa%e0%a7%87%e0%a6%a4%e0%a7%87-%e0%a7%a8%e0%a7%ac-%e0%a6%9c%e0%a6%be%e0%a6%a8%e0%a7%81%e0%a7%9f%e0%a6%be%e0%a6%b0%e0%a6%bf-%e0%a6%a5%e0%a7%87%e0%a6%95/"> <!-- wp:paragraph -->
<p>চলতি মাসের ২১ থেকে ২৫ তারিখের মধ্যে দেশে করোনাভাইরাসের টিকা আসবে। আর এই টিকা দেওয়া শুরু হবে ফেব্রুয়ারির প্রথম সপ্তাহে। এ জন্য নিবন্ধন </a></p>
```

How can I solve this problem?
Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

Go with this function for paragraphs operations on content :
wpautop( string $pee, bool $br = true )

https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/wpautop/

Comment: Thanks, remove_filter('the_content', 'wpautop') is not working and I actually speaking of the default wraper <P> tag of the the_content() template tag. pls, explain, @MANOJ VASHIST

Comment: Stop this by adding the following to your functions.php file
remove_filter('term_description','wpautop');

Answer (score 0):

At last, I myself develop a solution to this problem. this is as follows:

```
function my_content() 
{
    echo trim(strip_tags(get_the_content()));
}

function get_my_content()
{
    return trim(strip_tags(get_the_content()));
}
```

And it worked fine for me.
Thanks all.